# React eslint and webpack unexpected token using static propTypes

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint

I have this code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTyps } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default function (ComposedComponent) {
    class RequireAuth extends Component {
        static propTypes = {
            router: React.PropTypes.object
        }
        componentWillMount() {
            this.checkAuth();
        }
        componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
            this.checkAuth();
        }

        checkAuth() {
            if (!this.props.authenticated) {
                this.context.router.push('login');
            }
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    {this.props.authenticated === true ? <ComposedComponent {...this.props} /> : null}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            authenticated: state.auth.authenticate
        };
    };

    return connect(mapStateToProps)(RequireAuth);

}
```

i want to ask why my eslint show error `unexpected token` and when I run webpack it return me error `unexpected token` too?. Unexpected token position is on `=` at `static propTypes`. I search on Google and some people doing exactly same like I do.

Thanks

Comment: Well what babel preset or transforms are you using?

Comment: @DominicTobias I'm using `laravel-webpack-official`. but on my babelrc `"presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-1"]`

Comment: It needs to have at least `stage-2` preset or if chosen manually then the `transform-class-properties` transform

Comment: And do you mean `laravel-elixir-webpack-official`?

Comment: @DominicTobias yes you are correct.

Comment: Hm strange it should work with the stage-1 preset, try adjusting the order of your presets in that array

Comment: @DominicTobias I try manually setup .babelrc using `stage-2` still return me an error

Comment: @DominicTobias still no luck i tried 0 ,1 ,2 and change the position.

Comment: It looks like you need to programatically use `Elixir.webpack.mergeConfig` to add presets, by default it is only using es2015

Comment: @DominicTobias yes it works! but looks like I'm going to use webpack dev server instead. and use gulp to combine my less. it less pain. thanks!